# How can I change the colour of recyclerView item on button pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment containing a `recyclerView`.

[image: fragment]

When a user presses on one of their recorded exercise sets, the particular set is highlighted green.

Basically this allows them to update the weight/ reps for that particular set if they want to.

[image: update fragment]

When a user then decides to press the update button, I will run a SQL query to update the weight/ reps as they entered, however I also need to deselect the selected set (recyclerView item).

I need the colour to return back to dark grey. How could this be achieved?

**Fragment** (Relative Code)

```
 @Override
    public void onExerciseClicked(int position) {

        if (recyclerItemClicked == false) {
            saveBtn.setText("Update");
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerItemClicked = true;
            double selectedWeight = adapter.getWeight(position);
            String selectedWeightString = Double.toString(selectedWeight);
            editTextWeight.setText(selectedWeightString);

            int selectedReps = adapter.getReps(position);
            String selectedRepsString = Integer.toString(selectedReps);
            editTextReps.setText(selectedRepsString);

        } else {
            clearBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            saveBtn.setText("Save");
            recyclerItemClicked = false;
        }
    }

    public void initRecyclerView() {
        adapter = new CompletedExercisesListAdapter2(allExercises, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CompletedExercisesListAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener;
    private List<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises = new ArrayList<>();
    public int adapterPos = -1;
    public boolean isSelected = false;
    public boolean swipeDetected = false;

    public CompletedExercisesListAdapter2(ArrayList<Log_Entries> allCompletedExercises, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
        this.allCompletedExercises = allCompletedExercises;
        this.onExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;

        if (viewType == 0) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderOne(view, onExerciseClickListener);
        }

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.completed_exercise_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderTwo(view, onExerciseClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            ViewHolderOne viewHolderOne = (ViewHolderOne) holder;

            Log.d("adapterPos", String.valueOf(adapterPos));
            Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderOne.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }

            viewHolderOne.textViewExerciseName.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderOne.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderOne.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderOne.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));

        } else if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            ViewHolderTwo viewHolderTwo = (ViewHolderTwo) holder;

            if (adapterPos == position) {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#567845"));
            } else {
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }

            if(adapterPos >-1 && swipeDetected == true){
                viewHolderTwo.relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_grey);
            }
            viewHolderTwo.textViewSetNumber.setText(String.valueOf(viewHolderTwo.getAdapterPosition() + 1));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewWeight.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getTotal_weight_lifted()));
            viewHolderTwo.textViewReps.setText(String.valueOf(allCompletedExercises.get(position).getReps()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allCompletedExercises.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        // if list is sorted chronologically
        if (position == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (allCompletedExercises.get(position).getChildExerciseName().equals(allCompletedExercises.get(position - 1).getChildExerciseName())) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewExerciseName;
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;

        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderOne(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewExerciseName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_ExerciseName3);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number56);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight78);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss0);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_relative);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            if (isSelected) {
                adapterPos = -1;
                isSelected = false;

            } else {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                isSelected = true;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textViewSetNumber;
        private TextView textViewWeight;
        private TextView textViewReps;
        OnExerciseClickListener mOnExerciseClickListener;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolderTwo(@NonNull View itemView, OnExerciseClickListener onExerciseClickListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewSetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Set_Number);
            textViewWeight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_weight);
            textViewReps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_repss);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_item_rel);
            mOnExerciseClickListener = onExerciseClickListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onExerciseClickListener.onExerciseClicked(getAdapterPosition());

            if (!isSelected) {
                adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
                isSelected = true;

            } else {
                adapterPos = -1;
                isSelected = false;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public interface OnExerciseClickListener {
        void onExerciseClicked(int position);
    }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like, after successful execution of your SQL query set background of that selected item or observe your SQL query result, if it is successful then change background else show alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate method in your adapter for clearing the selection.

```
public void clearSelection() {
    adapterPos = -1;
    isSelected = false;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call `adapter.clearSelection()` from your update click listener.

Comment: However, I have tried to call `adapter.clearSelection` inside `onSwiped` method and it is not doing anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Get rid of the logic which would change the color of the selected viewholder when any viewholder is swiped from your Adapter class. That logic is inside 'onBindViewHolder` which would only be called when binding recycled viewholder with new data.